# Why does npm run result in the error: "Router.use() requires a middleware function but a ' + gettype(fn)"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

This is my server.js file where I have defined routes for my application.

```
//modules
var express = require('express');
var secure = require('express-force-https');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var cfenv = require("cfenv");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var secureKeys = require('dotenv').config()
const cors = require('cors');


app.use(secure);
// app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
// Parse URL-encoded bodies (as sent by HTML forms)
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// Parse JSON bodies (as sent by API clients)
app.use(express.json());

//routers for recycling company
var cHomepageRouter = require("./routes/recyclingCompanyHomepage");
var cWasteAuditRouter = require("./routes/recyclingCompanyWasteAudit");
var cRegisterRouter = require("./routes/recyclingCompanyRegister");
var cLoginRouter = require("./routes/recyclingCompanyLogin");
var cInfomationRouter = require("./routes/recyclingCompanyInformation");
var cForgotRouter = require("./routes/wasteEntitiesForgotPassword");
var cResetRouter = require("./routes/recyclingCompanyResetPassword");
//routers for waste entities
var wHomepageRouter = require("./routes/wasteEntitiesHomepage");
var wWasteAuditRouter = require("./routes/wasteEntitiesWasteAudit");
var wRegisterRouter = require("./routes/wasteEntitiesRegister");
var wLoginRouter = require("./routes/wasteEntitiesLogin");
var wInfomationRouter = require("./routes/wasteEntitiesInformation");
var wForgotRouter = require("./routes/wasteEntitiesForgotPassword");
var wResetRouter = require("./routes/wasteEntitiesResetPassword");

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');

//recycling company routes
app.use('/', cHomepageRouter);
app.use("/company-register", cRegisterRouter);
app.use("/company-login", cLoginRouter);
app.use("company-reset", cResetRouter);
app.use("/comapny-audit-waste", cWasteAuditRouter);
app.use("/comapany-forgot-password", cForgotRouter);
app.use("/comapny-information", cInfomationRouter);
// waste entities routes
app.use("/w-entity", wHomepageRouter);
app.use("entity-register",wRegisterRouter);
app.use("/entity-login", wLoginRouter);
app.use("/entity-reset", wResetRouter);
app.use("/entity-waste-audit", wWasteAuditRouter);
app.use("/entity-forgot-password", wForgotRouter);
app.use("/entity-information", wInfomationRouter);

//nodemon server.js to run the server
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("To view your app, open this link in your browser: http://localhost:" + port);
});

module.exports = app;
```

This is the error that I get

```
PS C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\project\server> npm start

> cloudant-nodejs-crud@1.0.0 start C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\project\server
> node server.js

C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\project\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458
      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
    at Function.use (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\project\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\project\server\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:220:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.use (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\project\server\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:217:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Usr\Documents\GitHub\project\server\server.js:43:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cloudant-nodejs-crud@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cloudant-nodejs-crud@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-01T22_31_17_562Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\project\server>
```

Comment: The error is `TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object`, so somewhere you're passing in an object instead of a middleware function. Please make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) since we can't help you in the current state, especially since we don't see what any of your `./routes/*` files look like

Comment: Could you also include an example of any of the files living under the `routes` directory?

Comment: Which exact line of code does the error occur on?  Is it this one `app.use('/', cHomepageRouter);`?  If so, then `cHomepageRouter` is apparently not a Router object.  To help you further with that, we need to see what `./routes/recyclingCompanyHomepage` exports.  Please show us that file.  It seems likely that you haven't appropriately assigned `module.exports` in that file.  Or, it's also possible that `./routes/recyclingCompanyHomepage` has some circular dependency so it's `require()` doesn't actually work properly.

Comment: routes  
    Waste Entities Homepage.js  
    Waste Entities Waste Audit.js  
    Waste Entities Information.js  
    Waste Entities Login.js  
    Waste Entities Register.js  
    Waste Entities Reset password.js  
    Waste Entities Forgot password.js  
    Recycling Company Homepage.js  
    Recycling Company Waste Audit.js  
    Recycling Company Information.js  
    Recycling Company Login.js  
    Recycling Company Register.js  
    Recycling Company Reset password.js  
    Recycling Company Forgot password.js

Comment: Huh?  What does that last comment mean?  I could probably help you in a few minutes if you'd answer my previous question.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, you are right. The file is empty. Let me populate all the files with starter code and observe what happens

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. Now my code runs. @jfriend00 adding code to the files worked

Answer (score 1):

In looking at the stack trace, it appears that the error originates at:

```
C:\Users\Usr\Documents\GitHub\project\server\server.js:43:5
```

which would be this line:

```
app.use('/', cHomepageRouter)
```

That would mean that `cHomepageRouter` which comes from here:

```
var cHomepageRouter = require("./routes/recyclingCompanyHomepage");
```

is not a Router or middleware function.  So, apparently the file `./routes/recyclingCompanyHomepage` does not properly assign `module.exports` to be the Router object that you are expecting it to be.

---

FYI, this is a classic debugging case and these are steps you would benefit from learning so you can track down errors like this yourself:

1. Get error in console.
2. Examine stack trace and determine what file and line the error originates on
3. Based on what that line of code is doing and the specific error you get, do further debugging to examine what the exact values are that are involved in this error.
4. In this specific case, you should do a `console.log(cHomepageRouter)` and see what it is.  Chances are you would see that it's not a Router function and then you would know to look further in the file that `cHomepageRouter` comes from.